# Truffle web3.eth.sign produces wrong signature

Tags: truffle, contract-debugging, signature, truffle-test, ecrecover

Somehow truffle produces an invalid signature.
To clarify this I imported the private key of the first Ganache account to metamask and compared the results.

The following code used in a chrome console returns the following (verifiable correct) signature:

```
// frontend
let msg = web3.sha3("truffle"); // => 0x28610e27d085e348e6ebd0da2c982947eddf7d308b82e951a896432cdac99a74
let sig;
web3.eth.sign(web3.eth.accounts[0], msg, (err, res) => {
  if(!err) {
    sig = res;
  }
})

// sig => 0xb453386b73ba5608314e9b4c7890a4bd12cc24c2c7bdf5f87778960ff85c56a8520dabdbea357fc561120dd2625bd8a904f35bdb4b153cf706b6ff25bb0d898d1c
```

Here's the code in truffle which should produce the same signature - but doesn't.

```
// Truffle:
let first = accounts[0];
let msg = web3.sha3("truffle");
let sig = await web3.eth.sign(first, msg)
// sig => 0x511fafdf71306ff89a063a76b52656c18e9a7d80d19e564c90f0126f732696bb673cde46003aad0ccb6dab2ca91ae38b82170824b0725883875194b273f709b901
```

This sucks as I am trying to test my contracts which rely on these signatures.

Comment: what is `first`?

Comment: first is the first account. I edited the question.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently it's an issue with Truffle, see this [issue here](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli/issues/243). More info [here](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/2215) and [here](https://github.com/JoinColony/colonyNetwork/pull/205).

Comment: No solution yet?